# Using Date as Constant in expressions

Tags: sas

I'm having trouble calling a date within an if statement. My date is, for example, "2001-08-05". I am trying to subset my data based on the date. So this is my code:

```
If ID = "Yes" and Date > 2001-08-05 then delete;
```

But this just doesn't do what I'm asking. I don't get an error, but it doesn't perform what I ask. I tried "2001-08-05"d. as well but this produced an error. Is there a certain way to read this format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper format for a date constant in SAS is `'ddmmmyyyy'd`, so:

```
if ID = 'Yes' and Date > '05Aug2001'd
```

You can use either single or double quotes to delimit the constant.  The month name in the constant is case insensitive.

On a side-note, if you need to do a date-time constant in SAS, the format is `'ddmmmyyyy:hh:mm:ss'dt`.  Notice the suffix becomes `dt` rather than just `d` and there is a semi-colon between the date and time.

Comment: SAS does not care whether you use single or double quotes as the enclosing quotes for string or other literals.  In fact if you want to reference macro variables or macro functions inside of the quoted strings you need to use double quote characters instead of the single quote (apostrophe) characters.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could try to covert character to date

```
If ID = "Yes" and Date > input('2001-08-05',yymmdd10.) then delete;
```